# Como inserto un id de una tabla a otra tabla en Mysql con PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

alguien me puede decir como hago para insertar el Id de una tabla a otra, lo que quiero hacer es que al momento de guardar un artículo, este se asocie con el id del usuario que esta logueado en ese momento y guardarlo en la tabla de artículos.

Estas son mi tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este el lo que se guarda en la tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este el codigo que utilizo

```
?php 

include("Conexion.php");

$objConexion = Conectarse ();

$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$descri = ['descripcion'];

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])){
    header("location:login.html");
}

$iduser=$_SESSION ['id_usuario'];

$insertarart = "INSERT INTO tbl_articulos (Titulo_Art,Descripcion) 
VALUES ('$titulo','$descri')";
$resultadoinsert = $objConexion->query($insertarart) or die($objConexion->error);

if($resultadoinsert > 0){

    echo "<script>
    alert('Registro Exitoso');
    window.location = 'iniciologin.html';
    </script>";
}
else{
    echo "<script>
    alert('Error al Registrase');
    window.location = 'iniciologin.html';
    </script>";

}

?>
```

Siempre me dice que el registro es exitoso pero no me guarda el Id del usuario logueado, ni el titulo del articulo ni la descripcion.

Articulo en html

```
<form  method="POST" action="guardararticulo.php" >
    <div id="contenido">
        <h2 name="titulo">Articulos para Mostrar</h2>
        <p name="descripcion">Contenido de la página Contenido de la página Contenido de la página Contenido de la página Contenido de la página
            Contenido de la páginaContenido de la páginaContenido de la páginaContenido de la páginaContenido de la página
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Guardar" name="guardar">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Saludos. Espero haber comprendido bien tu duda; lo que sucede es que la sesión en PHP y MySQL son dos ambientes distintos (aun corriendo en el mismo servidor); tienes que obtener el **identificador** de sesión del usuario y pasarlo como parte del `INSERT`; otra "opción" es que la misma sesión de MySQL la uses para insertarlo. Respecto a no guarda *articulo* ni *descripcion* mira si los datos los envias por `POST` y existen tal cual lo llamas; ademas `$descri = ['descripcion'];` no indicas si es `POST` o `GET`.

Comment: Si, efectivamente me hacia falta el post en la variable del GET, gracias.